# TYPO3 v10 - Getting feUser Object using context API in eID_include

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-10.x

Code that i used and need to update for V10

```
    $this->feUser = EidUtility::initFeUser();
```

When using the following code (a random) controller, the context gives me the correct login feUser object.

```
    $context = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(Context::class);
    $user = $context->getAspect('frontend.user');
    DebuggerUtility::var_dump($user);
```

When using the same code in an `eID_include` class **No** **userObject** is given.

Specificly in the following class

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['FileDumpEID.php']['checkFileAccess']['xxx'] = My\Class\Hooks\FileDumpHook:class
```

Is there a need of bootstrapping context?

Comment: I run into the same struggle now. Did you find a solution? If I create a middleware which extends the frontend user authenticator middleware and places this middleware before the eid middleware I have to create the context too and if I check this context inside the file dump hook it seems that something did not work as expected, because the user groups are missing and the isLoggedIn method returns false.

Comment: @Fox I have yet not found a working solution, work for this is on hold. If you find a solution example, gladly post below.

Answer (score 2):

Since the `TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Middleware\EidHandler` middleware is executed before the `TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Middleware\FrontendUserAuthenticator` middleware in the middleware's order, I don't think that this is possible.

If you need parts of the frontend handling you either can add an own middleware with a dependency of `TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Middleware\FrontendUserAuthenticator` or use a page Object in TypoScript.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. You may change the order of Middlewares: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/RequestHandling/Index.html

I've created a new file RequestMiddlewares.php inside the "Configuration" directory of my extension:

```
<?php

return [
    'frontend' => [
        'typo3/cms-frontend/eid' => [
            'disabled' => true
        ],
        'typo3/cms-frontend/eid-new' => [
            'target' => \TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Middleware\EidHandler::class,
            'after' => [
                'typo3/cms-frontend/tsfe',
            ],
            'before' => [
                'typo3/cms-frontend/prepare-tsfe-rendering',
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

You have to flush TYPO3 and PHP Cache and check the ordering in "Configuration" backend module (select "HTTP Middlewares (PSR-15)").

With this setup it is possible to get the context property 'frontent.user'

```
$context = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(Context::class);

if($context->getPropertyFromAspect('frontend.user', 'isLoggedIn')) {
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Since i was recommended not to change the core middleware stack i added my own middleware which is a copy of the EidMiddleWare.

In the following pull request you can find two examples. 
[Pull request](https://github.com/beechit/fal_securedownload/pull/147/files)

Comment: This is a bad idea because you change an internal marked configuration see https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/10.4/typo3/sysext/frontend/Configuration/RequestMiddlewares.php#L25-L31. Have a look at the answer of Sebastian Fischer which is the correct solution though.